# User TFS sessions get disconnected

Tags: team-foundation-server

From a while we are observing a strange issue with TFS - User sessions.
we are having a isolated environment(AD and TFS are set up in a different than local domain) for TFS .
Users report that their sessions on TFS/Visual studio get disconnected and after a while, they connect automatically.
I dont find anything suspicious in logs as well, as to if there is any tfs/db getting disconnected.

Can some one guide me how can i track the user session, as to why they get disconnected

Thanks,
Pasha

Comment: not sure how correct this could be, but still i am testing this.
I found a similar issue, may be helpful.[link](http://hastobe.net/blogs/stevemorgan/archive/2008/08/25/stop-visual-studio-prompting-for-tfs-credentials.aspx)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Another input,

Also enabled windows authentication in SQL to reduce the timeouts.!

-pasha

Answer (score 0):

One way to address this i found a workaround for this.
[workaround solution](http://hastobe.net/blogs/stevemorgan/archive/2008/08/25/stop-visual-studio-prompting-for-tfs-credentials.aspx) to fix local user credentials.
This may happen when users dont select password remember while entering credentials.

Thanks,
Pasha